# eastpanel stuck behind center because of scrollbar

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces

I know, this kind of topic was discussed a lot of times, but I have found no solution for my problem.
I got a layout with a north-panel, an east-panel, a west-panel and a center-panel.

Inside my east panel I use an `accordionPanel`. If the content of my open accordion tabs is to big for my page a `scrollbar` is rendered on the right side.
But this `scrollbar` causes a layout problem, a small part of my `eastpanel` is now behind my center panel.

Is there a way, to prevent my `eastpanel` from being behind the cnter panel or ist there a possibility to make the `scrollbar` invisible, but scrolling must be enabled.

This code, removes the `scrollbar`, but also disables scolling.
Code: Select all

```
<p:layoutUnit  position="east" size="420" header="#{labels.inspektor}" resizable="true" style="overflow:hidden !important;"> 
    <p:outputPanel id="eastPanel">                  
          <ui:include src="#{cmsEnviroment.cmsPages.get(cmsEastState.activePage)}" />                  
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Hope someone get a hint for me.

Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not solved yet, but found a workaround, which is OK for the moment:

```
<p:layoutUnit  position="east" size="420" header="#{labels.inspektor}" resizable="false" style="overflow:hidden !important;"> 
    <p:outputPanel id="eastPanel">
          <p:scrollPanel style="width:420px;height:810px" mode="native"> 
                <ui:include src="#{cmsEnviroment.cmsPages.get(cmsEastState.activePage)}" />
          </p:scrollPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:layoutUnit>
```